# How to access fields of a pointer's value on parse.com with iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am designing a database. According to documentation, when number of relationships are greater than 100 and there is extra fields, I must design a `Join Table`. I designed this `Join Table` by having two pointer value.

1. This pointer value is pointing to `_User`. Later I need only rows for `currUser`.
2. This pointer value is the `objectId` of another table which is an entity. My question is, how can I write a query to return objects for this table in `queryfortable`.

Let's say:

```
Table _User
Table Entity
Table Join ---> objectId   Pointer1(_User)  Pointer2(Event)
```

This look like this:

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

First I tried in `viewDidLoad` to get array of invitedUser from cloud and later in `queryForTable`:

```
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" containedIn:_inviteList];
```

but I need to access _inviteList.objectId which is not possible!

I tried to use innerQuerry or relation query. but as I just started learning parse I am not able to implement this.

```
PFUser *friendPointer = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query2 =  [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
[query2 whereKey:friendPointer containedIn:_inviteList];
return query2;
```

This also did not work for me.

```
    PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Invite"];
    [innerQuery whereKey:@"invitedUser" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Event"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:innerQuery];
    return query;
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me to write this query or re-design my table in order to have access to this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pleaser try this code and give me review

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Invite"];
[query whereKey:@"invitedUser" equalTo:user];
[query includeKey:@"invitedUser"];
[query includeKey:@"eventId"];
[query orderByDescending:@"updatedAt"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         for (PFObject *underobject in [objects reverseObjectEnumerator])
         {
             PFUser *user1 = underobject[@"invitedUser"];
             NSLog(@"invitedUser is :%@",user1);
         }
     }
}];
```